# Is there an approved way to classificate Java-Classes based on their functionalities?

Tags: java, class, object, methods

Some Classes are made just to create new kinds of objects,
others are made just to create new methods,
others both,
other.. etc.

Is there an approved method, an approved **way to classificate** Java-Classes based on their **functionalities**?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Have a look at Java design patterns. Object creation falls under Creational Patterns.

Sample reference: https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/java

Comment: A design pattern, in the "concrete world", is made by one or more classes?

Comment: @tauto A pattern can have many different classes involved, but some have only one like Builder, Factory, etc. I suggest you read more about design patterns, because there are many different patterns for different purposes/problems.